# A class One with data members int a and char b inherits from another class Two with data members float f and int x

Tags: c++, c++11

I need class definitions for class One and Two, where:
**1. Objects of both the classes are able to access all the data members of both the classes.**
**2. Only the members of class One can access all the data members of both the classes.**

```
//case 2
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Two{
    public:
        float f;
        int x;
};

class One: public Two{
    private:
        int a;
        char b;
};
```

I have tried the 2nd part. Is it correct? And can you help me out with the 1st part.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre] of *your own* attempt, and [edit] your question to show it together with a description of the problems you have with it (and an actual question).

Comment: Also please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what exactly it is you want. You can do it with inheritance.
I'd suggest you to read some tutorials about this, like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-c/

You can easily try out wether it is correct or not; just compile it and look what's happening.

2:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Your classes go here


int main()
{
    One o;
    o.f= 1;
    o.x= 2;
    o.a = 10;
    o.b = 11;

    Two t;
    t.f= 21;
    t.x = 22;

    cout << "One: f: " << o.f << endl;
    cout << "One: x: " << o.x << endl;
    // and so on

    return 0;
}
```

For the first part, think about having a base class for both, one and two, to store data both sub-classes can access.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for answering. I have got the solution as below:
**(1)**

```
class Two { 
 protected: 
   float f; 
   int x; 
};

class One:private Two { 
  int a; 
  char b; 
};
```

**(2)**

```
class Two { 
  public: 
    float f; 
    int x; 
}; 

class One:public Two { 
  public: 
    int a; 
    char b; 
};
```

Comment: 1. Objects of both the classes are able to access all the data members of both the classes => in your 1. objects of Two are not able to access objects of One

2. Only the members of class One can access all the data members of both the classes => in your 2. everyone can access everything